# Can the AutoComplete attribute be set within the password field in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, penetration-testing

During an external Pen-Test, it was observed that the login screen's password field for our SaaS product should be using `AutoComplete="off"`.

We are using Azure AD B2C non-social accounts and custom policies; It is my understanding that the B2C mechanism injects its own content as a form into the `div` of the supplied template. Is it possible to influence the placement of this attribute? [Customize the user interface with HTML templates in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>My Product Brand Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="api"> [[ INSERTED HERE ]] </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have found references to modify the fields using client-side JavaScript, such as [Azure B2C password field text and placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942340/azure-b2c-password-field-text-and-placeholder) and [Azure B2C Password field value visible button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942340/azure-b2c-password-field-text-and-placeholder) but would prefer to avoid manipulating the DOM like this.

Note: I am aware that the guidance of `AutoComplete="off"` is that many of the browsers ignore the setting anyway, but I'm looking for an affirmative code change for compliance or a clear mitigation rationale.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to adjust the attribute is using client side JS. As you mention, it hardly works, browsers try very hard to auto populate regardless.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy