Azure AD B2C autocomplete "missing user/pass" error message management
We are using Azure AD B2C with custom policies and a custom design (HTML and CSS). Everything works fine, but we would like to fix one specific issue.
Scenario:
On the sign-in page, if a user forgets to type their username and password and clicks on “Sign in,” an error message in red appears, prompting the user to enter their username and password.
When the user manually enters the information, the error message automatically disappears.
However, when the user selects the autocomplete option from saved accounts, the error message persists, even though the user can still log in.
Notes:
When using a flow that does not involve custom policies, the error message is automatically removed.
When using a blank policy starter pack, the error persists, which suggests that the issue is not related to design changes.
Request for Assistance:
Could you please help us adjust the settings so that the error message is removed once the fields are autofilled from saved accounts?
Thank you for your assistance.
I tried to play around with custom html but since Azure handles selfassert part, I had 0 success..

The issue may be in the browser (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908073/can-the-autocomplete-attribute-be-set-within-the-password-field-in-azure-b2c)  It says many browsers ignore the setting.  Try changing the User-Agent which specified the type of browser : https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/windows

The desired behavior can be achieved by updating the version of the page layouts.
Azure AD B2C allows to specify which version of the page layouts to use by editing the DataUri elements value of ContentDefinition elements within custom policy file.
In custom policy files (typically in TrustFrameworkBase.xml), find the ContentDefinitions section. This section contains definitions for the different page layouts.
The DataUri element, located inside ContentDefinition element, defines the version of the user interface (html page layout) used by Azure B2C.
Changing this value is a way to change the page layout version. With this change it's possible to get newer features, enhancements, and visual styles (and as well as bugs, if any).
The DataUri value has the following pattern:
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:page-name:version</DataUri>

For example, for 'selfasserted' page name with the version 2.1.14 DataUri element would appear as:
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.14</DataUri>

To update to a newer version (let's say it would be 2.1.30), change it to:
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.30</DataUri>

A list of available page layout versions for the self-asserted page (selfasserted) page can be found here, for the unified sign-in and sign-up page with password reset link (unifiedssp) - here
